# Undefined array parameter with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't see why this function is returning undefined:

```
function sumArray(array) {
  array.reduce(function(result, item) {
    return result + item;
  })
}

array = [1,2,3]

sumArray(array)
```

I've tried something similar and it works ok (below), so I'm not sure if it's specific to the parameter being an array?

```
function sayNumber(num) {
 return num + 1;
} 

num = 1

sayNumber(num)
```

Comment: Because your function `sumArray` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Any function that doesn't explicitly return something returns "undefined" instead. You just invoke the array.reduce method but your not returning it so it really doesn't have anything to return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually need is to add one more `return` statement.

```
function sumArray(array) {
  //here
  return array.reduce(function(result, item) {
    return result + item;
  });
}

array = [1,2,3];

sumArray(array);
//6
```

Comment: @safikabis, happy to help and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this or any other answer solved your problem, please, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The function `sumArray` is not returning the result from `array.reduce`. Insert a `return` before your `array.reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

It returns `undefined` because there is no return statement for the `sumArray` function.

(The anonymous function you pass to `reduce` has one, but that is a different function).

If you want to return the result of calling `array.reduce` when you have to say so explicitly:

```
return array.reduce(etc, etc…
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value of the function sumArray
Like this:

```
function sumArray(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(result, item) {
    return result + item;
  })
}
```